# async fetch in function

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am trying to create a function, that sends a request to my API with fetch & waits for the result - if it returns data, I want the function to return `true`, otherwise `false`.

```js
const loggedIn = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(ENDPOINT_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: query,
    })
  })
  const json = await response.json()

  // data gets logged
  console.log(json.data)

  if(json.data) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

If I call `loggedIn()`, I still receive `Promise {<pending>}`?

Comment: Yes, since it's an async function it returns a promise. Have you tried `const isLoggedIn = await loggedIn()`? Or just using a promise `then`?

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function returns a promise. From a caller's perspective, it's no different from any other function returning a promise. When you call it, you get a promise which you need to handle, not the value, because that would require blocking.

It sounds like you expected it to block your code. To get that, call it from another `async` function:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(await loggedIn()); // true or false
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, i am very new to async JS. I basically need to await the fetch response since i'd use this function to decide if a user is authenticated to see something. 
How would i go about saving this in a variable/function? (so i can use it with a ternary operator like this: `loggedIn() ? render() : redirect()`)

Comment: `const isLoggedIn = await loggedIn(); isLoggedIn? render() : redirect()` or just `await loggedIn() ? render() : redirect()`.